# Ask RegEx for solaris

Tags: regex, case, solaris

Does anyone know what the format is for these criteria?

```
bin::2:root,daemon

2

2

yes
```

I just want root, daemon and yes value in some case yes will change to no.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pauXBb/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow Ben,

You question wasn't very clear, but is this what you're looking for? If you give us a little more information, it's easier for us to help.

```regex
bin::\d+:(root,daemon) \d+ \d+ (yes)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/pauXBb/5

It stores `root, daemon` in the first capturing group, and `yes` in the second.

Comment: Hi @Addison, thank you for your response. here is the detail case (https://regex101.com/r/GUbxWq/1). i just need root,daemon and yes/no. kindly need your help.

Comment: @Ben Sorry, I'm having a little trouble understanding. Did you want `root, daemon` in one group, and `yes` or `no` in the other?

Comment: yes i want root,daemon and yes too forget about no. as example on https://regex101.com/r/GUbxWq/1 can you help me to create that regex. many thanks Addison.

Comment: Sure thing @Ben. Try this: https://regex101.com/r/pauXBb/5. I updated the answer too.